# Hamcrests NoSuchMethodError after multiple calls to mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I've got the common problem with NoSuchMethodError by org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch. It's very weird because it's only throwing when I try to mock one method with multiple arguments in one test. I guess my description can be not clearly, so I'll show it by example. This is my mock:

```
  private void mockParameterListOfTerminalGroup(TerminalGroup terminalGroup, List<Parameter> parameters) {
    Matcher<ParameterFilter> matcher = Matchers.<ParameterFilter> hasProperty("bean", hasProperty("scopeId", equalTo(terminalGroup.getId())));
    when(parameterDAO.getByExample(argThat(matcher))).thenReturn(parameters);
}
```

when it's called once in test, it's working clearly, but when I try to mock it for many times for different parameters its throwing NoSuchMethodError.

The dependencies are in right order:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
             <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The funny thing is that when I build the whole project with tests, this test passes, but when I run it as a single junit test, it fails.

Comment: hasProperty("scopeId", equalTo(terminalGroup.getId())) replace scopeid with Matcher.any, and also don't hard code your parameters instead used ArgumentMatchers for better results.

Comment: yeah I'm trying to change this Matcher to ArgumentMatchers, but I have little problems. don't really know how to implement that, trying with google :) thanks for advice

Comment: Could you provide more insides. The code looks totally valid. What is the output of the test? What parameter is being passed to `parameterDAO.getByExample` during the test? I have a doubt that it might not match. Try adding one more assert before the final one that will match the input parameter against the matcher you have. Something like `assertThat(argumentOfGetByExampleCall, matcher);`. It might help to understand the problem.

Comment: What could also be the problem is that the tests are not isolated during maven run. It might happen in case if you're using some additional framework for testing like spring-test (it loads its own context and reuses it, in some cases it might lead to dirty context after a particular run). Ensure your test is fully isolated (for instance spring-test does have mechanisms to force cleanup context)